# Join Elements in Prometheus Through Query (Instant)

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible to join elements in Prometheus in the scope of an instant query?

I have an element `job_last_run{jobname="somejob"}` where the value is a unix timestamp in seconds and another element `job_state{name="somejob"}` where the value is a numerical value correlating to a human-readable status of the job.

I would like to be able to run an instant query that would output table series data that can be ordered by the timestamp value from `job_last_run` and also for each element return the value from `job_state` matched by the name of the job that exists in each element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, effective ordering is limited to the very last step of PromQL so you can sort by value but not then join that. You would need to run the two queries separately and then join them in a script.